# How to determine AVSpeechSynthesizer speed Swift?

Tags: swift

Does anyone know how to determine the speed of the speech synthesizer? It's sounding really fast now?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var voice = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {
    var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:"This is a test")
    voice.speakUtterance(utterance)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reducing the speech rate, use rate property of AVSpeechUtterance class

```
    let speechUtterance: AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Sample text for speech")
    speechUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    print("Default Speech Rate: " + String(speechUtterance.rate))

    speechUtterance.rate = 0.3

    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    speechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(speechUtterance)
```